How to create ground truth poses (visual odometry) from the GPS data of KITTI dataset?
KITTI dataset contains task of Visual Odometry and you can download the ground truth poses that provided for the sequences of the specific task.
I want to combine IMU data for my Visual Odometry, but they are not provided for the sequences of the Visual Odometry task, only for the raw data. (another sequences).
The raw data contain oxts data.
The data format that provided:
lat:   latitude of the oxts-unit (deg) 
lon:   longitude of the oxts-unit (deg) 
alt:   altitude of the oxts-unit (m) 
roll:  roll angle (rad),    0 = level, positive = left side up,      range: -pi   .. +pi 
pitch: pitch angle (rad),   0 = level, positive = front down,        range: -pi/2 .. +pi/2 
yaw:   heading (rad),       0 = east,  positive = counter clockwise, range: -pi   .. +pi 
vn:    velocity towards north (m/s) 
ve:    velocity towards east (m/s) 
vf:    forward velocity, i.e. parallel to earth-surface (m/s) 
vl:    leftward velocity, i.e. parallel to earth-surface (m/s) 
vu:    upward velocity, i.e. perpendicular to earth-surface (m/s) 
ax:    acceleration in x, i.e. in direction of vehicle front (m/s^2) 
ay:    acceleration in y, i.e. in direction of vehicle left (m/s^2) 
az:    acceleration in z, i.e. in direction of vehicle top (m/s^2) 
af:    forward acceleration (m/s^2) 
al:    leftward acceleration (m/s^2) 
au:    upward acceleration (m/s^2) 
wx:    angular rate around x (rad/s) 
wy:    angular rate around y (rad/s) 
wz:    angular rate around z (rad/s) 
wf:    angular rate around forward axis (rad/s) 
wl:    angular rate around leftward axis (rad/s) 
wu:    angular rate around upward axis (rad/s) 
pos_accuracy:  velocity accuracy (north/east in m) 
vel_accuracy:  velocity accuracy (north/east in m/s) 
navstat:       navigation status (see navstat_to_string) 
numsats:       number of satellites tracked by primary GPS receiver 
posmode:       position mode of primary GPS receiver (see gps_mode_to_string) 
velmode:       velocity mode of primary GPS receiver (see gps_mode_to_string) 
orimode:       orientation mode of primary GPS receiver (see gps_mode_to_string) 

I can verify that my Visual Odometry code is working when I compare it to the visual odometry ground truth poses provided by KITTI for the VO task.
I tried to convert the GPS data to ENU for relative trajectory. but I am getting different results, the trajectories are not align, even if they looks the same. Any idea how to fix the creation of the ground truth poses from the raw data like they did in the visual odometry task.
